# Display a custom field with Rich Text Area fieldtype

Tags: custom-fields, textarea

In the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/examples.html), I don't see anything here on how to display a field with fieldtype of textarea(richtext)

How do I display that field?

Answer (score 1):

If the channel Field Type is set to 'Textarea (Rich Text)' then you can just use the Field Name as the tag - eg: `{your_rte_field}`.